# Python - How do i make this RNG program continue to run for x amount of times after generating the number once

Tags: python

So I have this random number generator program but I don't know how to change it from stopping after generating the certain number once to continuing to run for x amount of times and then displaying how many times it generated that certain number within the amount of times I wanted it to run.

```
from random import randint

attempts = 0

print("What would you like to test-roll today?")
print("(64, 128, 256, 384, 512, 1024, 5000")
inp = str(input())

lootTable = {"1024":1024,
             "128":128,
             "256":256,
             "5000":5000,
             "512":512,
             "384":384,
             "64":64}

while True:
    rnd = randint(1,lootTable[inp])
    attempts += 1
    print("Rolling for %s (1/%d), attempt %d" %(inp, lootTable[inp], attempts))
    if rnd == 1:
        break

print("%s acquired on attempt %d!" %(inp, attempts))
```

eg I would want it to run 1000 times and then tell me how many times it rolled the number 1 when generating numbers between 1 and 64.

This is just for personal use to simulate a drop table from a video game.

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify this program that does not do what you need; write a program that does what you need.

```
import random

def count_hits(attempts, max_random, number_to_hit):
  # Every time the random generator hits the right number,
  # add 1 to the sum. It will count the number of hits.
  # The _ is just a variable about the value of which you don't care. 
  return sum(1 for _ in range(attempts)
             if random.randint(1, max_random) == number_to_hit)

# Add a few input() calls, then print(count_hits(...))
```